# How to make a python loop that would run a program many times?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a program that I can use from the terminal but i would like to run it many times in a loop in python. Someone told me to use the subprocess.call function but I have some trouble understanding how that works.

From the terminal I usually run exactly this `./grezza_foresta -w "/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/Leiden/text_file/USA.g" -m 5 -e 0 > file_name.g` (the -w -m -e are option and the > is to create a file with the output)

So I tried something like that from what I've been told to do .

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["g++", "/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/C/forestenostre/grezza_foresta",  "/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/Leiden/text_file/USA.g"])
ntrial = input("How many trials? ")
for i in range(int(ntrial)):
    tmp=subprocess.call("/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/C/forestenostre/grezza_foresta")
    print(i,tmp)
```

I'm getting this error :

> ld: can't link with a main executable file '/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/C/forestenostre/grezza_foresta' for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It actually seems to be working in some way but I don't know how to add the options.

Comment: What you usually run from the terminal seems to be something else than you are trying to run from Python. On the terminal, you are not invoking `g++`.

Comment: You talk about a C program but then your code is invoking g++, and the file extension of what you seem to want to compile is `.g` which is not a standard extension for C *or* C++, and GNU g++ (nor Apple clang++, which is presumably what you’re using) has no handling for it according to the manual.

Comment: Ah ok ! Indeed I need to read more about this, I will add a comment in i'm still in trouble with that , thank you !

Comment: Sorry but I'm still lost , what I don't get is that I have the executable so I don't need to compile anything , just run it right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `-o` flag and change your C++ file suffix:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["g++", "-o", "/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/C/forestenostre/grezza_foresta",  "/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/Leiden/text_file/USA.cpp"])
ntrial = input("How many trials? ")
for i in range(int(ntrial)):
    tmp=subprocess.call("/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/C/forestenostre/grezza_foresta")
    print(i,tmp)
```